# How to add a decal onto texture for game asset

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have been looking all over the internet on how to add a decal or an image on a texture for a game asset model. The reason why I am mentioning its for a game asset is because it all needs to be one texture and model.

So what have I tried? Well I shrink wrapped an image to my model but couldn't bake it all into one texture and I have tried using the texture stencil tool but the result looked quite blurry.[image: Texture Stencil tool]

Comment: You could export your UV layout to photoshop or Gimp and make your textures and decals there and import it back to blender

Comment: @Emir maybe but I would prefer not to.

Comment: you can use the default (Draw) brush in Stencil mode and paint what you want on your current texture